Discrepancy of everyday Chinese and the English translation in 答林正字书
The excerpt is taken out of the book 中国历代名人书信选 published by 中国出版集团中国对外翻译出版公司 as follows:
吾子以老成之智，蕴救世之心，一言悟主，俯拾初筮。
Translation given in everday Chinese in the book：。。。。。用一句话感悟主上，就拔到了头筹（译者：张华）
Translation given in English in the book:...you won the heart of the emperor with an essay of your's. And you were enlisted in the official service as easily as to pick up something from the ground.(Translated by 陈启达，a research professor of China Institute of Contemporary International Relations)
Which is the right one?


Which is the right one?

Neither.
蕴: yùn: 五蕴：色蕴，受蕴，想蕴，行蕴，识蕴
五蕴: 乃佛教之核心概念，
五蕴: a core concept in Buddhism,
用以阐述众生身心之构成及其生命体验之五大要素。
used to express the five essential constituent components of all living beings and their life experience
救世: 拯济世人；匡救世弊。
救世: save people; save the world from its troubles.
悟：感悟、觉悟
悟主: 使主上觉悟。
become enlightened
俯拾: 读音是fǔ shí，汉语词语，
俯拾: 意思是有俯身拾取；
俯拾: meaning is stoop to pick up (something);
引申以喻成事之易；屈尊下取。
(The) Extended meaning is do something with ease (as easy as bending down to pick up something);
筮shì
⒈ 古代用蓍草占卦：
In ancient times yarrow (stalks) were used for divination:
“龟为卜，策为筮”。《礼记·曲礼上》曰：“龟为卜，策为筮”。
说明古时卜用龟甲，筮用蓍草。
Explanation: in ancient times tortoise shells were used for divination and yarrow stalks were used for divination.
筮仕（古人将出外做官，先占卦问吉凶。
筮仕 (The Ancients, before going out to take up a post as an official, first consulted divination to see whether the signs were auspicious or not.
后称初次做官为“筮仕”）。
later, “筮仕”was used as the name of a new official).
Thus we have:
吾子以老成之智，
My son use mature wisdom,
蕴救世之心，
(and) the five skandhas of the mind that saves the world
一言悟主，
be enlightened by a word,
俯拾初筮。
easily reach the first post (towards Buddha)

Sorry to say so but your version seems to have nothing to do with the ones given by the book. I am more confused.

吾子以老成之智，蕴救世之心，一言悟主，俯拾初筮。
My translation to modern Chinese:

我的門生藉着老道的機智, 蕴藏的救世之心, 一番話點醒了君主, 出仕做官將如俯身拾物。

"筮"(占卜用物) - 筮仕(初次出仕做官)。
"俯身拾物" 指 "隨地拾來, 容易之意".

Thanks, You mean he will be easy in his career in future, and the translator said he got the job easily with his essay. So your version is another one, right?

You can change 一番話 to 一篇文章. The important thing is that his views/ideas were well accepted by the master, thus making his future brighter.
